# Registering Composite Classes in Unity

Tags: asp.net, unity-container

in my implementation, I have an interface as: `ICachingManager`. I've got now one implementation. I also created a manager class as:

```
public class CachingManager
{
    #region Members
    private ICachingManager service;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public CachingManager(ICachingManager service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void EnCache<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        this.service.EnCache<T>(key, value);
    }

    public T DeCache<T>(string key)
    {
        return this.service.DeCache<T>(key);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In case I had one implementation, then I can easily register the CachingManager class with Unity, automatically Unity resolves and injects the ICachingManager.

In case I had more than one implementation using named types, then how can I can make use of Unity? Do I need to make use of an Abstract Factory to decide on which named type to initialize?

Is it a good idea to make use of such a composite class or use directly implementations of the interface with Abstract Factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create an abstract factory. You can inject a given named implementation:

```
public class MyClient
{
    [Dependency("NamedManager")]
    public ICachingManager CachingManager { get; set; }

    // or in the constructor
    public MyClient([Dependency("NamedManager")] ICachingManager cachingManager) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

or you can configure the container to do the same thing:

```
public class MyClient
{
    public MyClient(ICachingManager cachingManager) {
       // ...
    }
}
...
void ContainerBuilder() {
   ...
   Container.RegisterType<MyClient>(
       new InjectionConstructor(
          new ResolvedParameter<ICachingManager>("NamedManager")));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks onof :). In case I don't know the name at compile time, instead I read it from a config file, then I need a factory? One more thing, I am trying to see how to configure Uinty 2.0 with a type that doesnt implement any interface, whats the syntax in config file? thanks a lot

Comment: 1) you need a factory if the name of the dependency is given at runtime and it can change during the execution 2) to register a type: <register type="MyType"></register>. You don't need the "mapTo" attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=PandP.20).aspx#config_registerelement

Comment: Thanks Onof! Ideas getting clear now on DI and Factory ;) Thanks to you.